# Variable debounceTime based on conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to have a debounceTime value set to something that changes based on a condition? I have a behavior subject setup as so (and please tell me if I'm doing even this part wrong):

```
this.searchSubject.asObservable().debounceTime(1000).subscribe(x => this.emitFilters())
```

I'd like the debounce time to be different based on certain filter conditions, but when I try to throw a function in there, VS Code complains that it's not valid.

I also took a look at debounce, which seems to take a type of variable, but from the documentation, I can't seem to figure it out (the function I threw in returned the wrong type according to VS Code, even though I copied from documented code). I'm doing all this in Angular 2 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you see documentation that suggested that .debounceTime would accept a function? It is well documented [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime) with the following signature:

```
public debounceTime(dueTime: number, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
```

The method you're looking for is [debounce](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounce) which, according to the documentation:

```
Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span determined by another Observable has passed without another source emission.
It's like debounceTime, but the time span of emission silence is determined by a second Observable.
```

Here is it's signature:

```
public debounce(durationSelector: function(value: T): Observable | Promise): Observable
```

So, all you have to do to accomplish the behavior you're after is to set up another Observable which will provide the interval at which to debounce.

You could do this using another Subject which you could call .next() on according to application logic to provide the new wait period.

```
let debounceSubject = new Subject<number>();
let debounceObservable$ = debounceSubject.asObservable();

// Somewhere else in code you'll do debounceSubject.next(1000); for example
```

And finally you would set up your new debounce like this:

```
this.searchSubject.asObservable()
    .debounce(() => debounceObservable$).subscribe(x => this.emitFilters())
```

More examples of using .debounce can be found [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html) (great website for learning rxjs) including working examples with jsBin and jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I looked at the docs for debounce, but as you said, it uses observables. Unless I'm not fully seeing it (which is likely given the mental shift observables is forcing), it doesn't really do what I want, though thanks to those docs, looks like takeLast -> reduce -> filter may, if I can figure out how to use reduce...

Comment: I decided to try our your solution, for learning if nothing else, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't debounce, even though I'm passing it the required Subject observable, and passing it new values as appropriate. Somehow, it also broke other code, so I'm guessing my general use/structure is wrong :/ Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: If you can give a more complete code sample for where you are now, or better yet a Plunker or something I can take a look and try to help

Comment: I appreciate it. I'll post something up, or put up another question if that's more appropriate.